# Add a column during getting data with ThreadPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, scrape

I want to read different pages from the link below with different numbers using ThreadPoolExecutor and save the related numbers to a dataframe as a new column.

https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1030/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1

The numbers change as below:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pandas import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
import requests


def download_file(url):
    url_info = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    jdata = url_info.json()
    return jdata


nums = [1030,1031,1040,1050,1020,1021,1010,1023]
urls= [f"https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/{i}/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1" for i in nums]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=14) as executor:
     for url in urls:
         sleep(0.1)
         processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))

for index, task in enumerate(as_completed(processes)):
    jdata = task.result()
    tmp = json_normalize(jdata)
    tmp["num"] = nums[index]
df = df.append(tmp)
print(df.head())
```

In the code above I have tried to read the data using multi-threading and and the related number to each json response as a new column of `df` dataframe. But this code does not work, because of using multi-threading the order of `nums`'s numbers are not the same as scraped json responses. What should I do?

Comment: you could `enumerate()` urls and send `(index, url)` and return `(index, jdata)` so later you can use `index` to sort results in correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

...

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=14) as executor:
     rv = executor.map(download_file, urls)

for index, jdata in enumerate(rv):
    tmp = json_normalize(jdata)
    tmp["num"] = nums[index]
    df.append(tmp)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: What should I import to use `mp`?

Comment: I had made a mistake, and now that you edited your question everything looks fine. `map` preserves in the results the order of the iterable passed for the arguments. Check `starmap` for other useful interface.

Comment: I write it, but when I want to run `for index, task in enumerate(as_completed(rv)):` I face an Error: `Exception has occurred: TypeError x
unhashable type: 'list'` for the next `for` loop

Comment: You have to eliminate the `as_completed` call. Read `map` documentation: the return value has the results of the function calls.

Comment: Would you please write the second `for` loop?

Comment: Oh, gosh... I keep leaving small mistakes in the code. `rv` is the equivalent of `rv= [download_file(f) for f in urls]`, but using a thread pool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239982/discussion-between-azelcer-and-v-nouri).